# Select all using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Trying the mongodb tutorial at http://try.mongodb.org/

this code :

```
> db.users.insert({name: 'Sue', languages: ['scala', 'lisp']});
> db.users.find
function () { [native code] }
```

Is not returning any results. Is this not the correct method to select all from a document and print the results to screen ?

Comment: try adding the parentheses at the end i.e., `db.users.find()`

Comment: By default the shell will actually show you the code of the function rather than run it if you withhold the parantheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `db.users.find()`.

The mongodb shell is based on Javascript. To call a function, add parenthesis. Without parenthesis, you are referring to the function itself.